# Apply function to all files in a folder and save the results in the same folder

Tags: python, pandas, file, directory, path

i have a small doubt here...
i'm trying to open a file with os.listdir(), apply a function and then save the results in a given path.
the problem, is that when i do so, it only saves the last file treated, not every files as i expected. i implemented tqm and it recognizes the 207 folders inside de directory (path) but only saves the last one.

Here is the begining and the end of the code for simplicity. the treatment in the middle is reducing, and normalizing columns.. nothing extraordinary.

'''

```
def ind_quant_table_full(repository_path, ionization_mode, file_extention, data_process_origin, use_ion_identity, min_score_final, min_ConfidenceScore, min_ZodiacScore):
    
   path = os.path.normpath(repository_path)
   samples_dir = [directory for directory in os.listdir(path)]

   for directory in tqdm(samples_dir):

      quant_path = os.path.join(path, directory, ionization_mode, directory + '_features_quant_' + ionization_mode + '.csv')


      try:
           df = pd.read_csv(quant_path, sep=',')

      except FileNotFoundError:
           continue
      except NotADirectoryError:
           continue

      df = pd.read_csv(quant_path, sep= ',')

      [do something to df]

      df

   pathout_folder = os.path.join(path, 'results/')
   os.makedirs(pathout_folder, exist_ok=True)
   pathout = os.path.join(pathout_folder, directory +'_' + ionization_mode + '_quant_annotations.tsv')
   df.to_csv(pathout, sep ='\t')
   print(f'Result are in : {pathout_folder}')'''
```

could you give me some insides?

Answer (score 0):

apparently you forgot about the indentation in the last part of the function

```py
def ind_quant_table_full(repository_path, ionization_mode, file_extention, data_process_origin, use_ion_identity, min_score_final, min_ConfidenceScore, min_ZodiacScore):
    
   path = os.path.normpath(repository_path)
   samples_dir = [directory for directory in os.listdir(path)]

   for directory in tqdm(samples_dir):

      quant_path = os.path.join(path, directory, ionization_mode, directory + '_features_quant_' + ionization_mode + '.csv')


      try:
           df = pd.read_csv(quant_path, sep=',')

      except FileNotFoundError:
           continue
      except NotADirectoryError:
           continue

      df = pd.read_csv(quant_path, sep= ',')

      [do something to df]

      df

      pathout_folder = os.path.join(path, 'results/')
      os.makedirs(pathout_folder, exist_ok=True)
      pathout = os.path.join(pathout_folder, directory +'_' + ionization_mode + '_quant_annotations.tsv')
      df.to_csv(pathout, sep ='\t')
      print(f'Result are in : {pathout_folder}')'''
```

Comment: thanks, still i got the same results.. just the last files was treated and saved when i applies the function: 'ind_quant_table_full(repository_path, ionization_mode)'